# How to cut row from sheet1 and paste onto sheet2 - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

i need help. I have multiple sheets.

```
Rejected Candidates
Interested Candidates
Candidate Track
Onboarding Track
```

Now I have these formulas:

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Interested_Candidates,Interested_Candidates[Rejected]="yes"),MATCH(A5:M5,Interested_Candidates[#Headers],0))
```

This is for if rejected column is "yes" then they're moved into rejected candidate sheet

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Interested_Candidates,Interested_Candidates[Interested?]="yes"),MATCH(A5:D5,Interested_Candidates[#Headers],0))
```

This is for if interested column is "yes" then they're moved into Candidate track sheet

```
=FILTER('Candidate Track'!A6:E100,'Candidate Track'!K6:K100="Job Offer Accepted")
```

This is for if the job offer has been accepted, they're moved into onboarding track sheet.

Problem is, I want to CUT the row and paste it depending on the value.

Once that's done, I need it to remove that blank row and move the below row that would be filled up if there is one

At the moment, the rows are getting messy & when I click on yes for one candidate for example to reject - it doesn't input it into a new row but copies onto an existing row on the rejected sheet.

Sorry if the explanation is poor, but will be explained if there are questions. any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: Formulas cannot CUT.  They can only reproduce the values wanted in the other sheet.  If you remove the value from the primary sheet the formula on the other sheet will loose that line also.  What you describe will require vba.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking for VBA coding and trying it but unfortunately I've conjured up nothing. Any help is appreciated, and I assume they'll need to be separate for each sheet too

Comment: Yes, you'll need a VBA solution. When I was new with VBA I would record a macro and then modify/generalize to my particular use case. Good luck

Comment: No, you would put vba in a worksheet_change event on the main sheet that moves the line to appropriate sheet on the change of the cell.  There are many tutorials online that will show you how to use this event.

Comment: Understood, it's for work so we're more organised and with the kind of industry we're in i've created an excel that works for what we need it to for now but these final bits would be the cherry. Struggling to find time to spend more time on it at present which is the frustrating part right now tbf

Comment: Sounds like it is time for your company to spend some money.  They can either, pay for one of their employees to take classes, or hire someone with the knowledge, or find a third party subcontractor to do the work.  Either way this is not the forum for free code.  Good Luck.

Comment: Advanced filter?